# Connection checker Script on Python

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I was working on a connection everytime checker script on Python, trying to implement it by crontabs on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu desktop 21.04. The code is the next:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from ping3 import ping
from time import sleep
program_flag=LED(24)

while True:
   ping_test=ping('8.8.8.8')
     if isinstance(ping_test, float):
     program_flag.on()
     else:
     program_flag.off()
     print(ping_test)
     print(program_flag)
sleep(3)
```

This code works fine for me, but the problem comes when I try to put this script on crontab. I read something about infinite loops or while loops on crontabs, and I think that they doesn't work. What is the best solution for this? The target is configure a gpio with a 1 or 0 depending if connection works fine or not.

EDIT: my crontab line: @reboot python3 /bin/connection_test.py &

Thank you so much!

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to run the script as a daemon -- this link may help https://ronanlopes.me/daemonize-running-python-script-daemon/

Answer (score 0):

I have checked line by line, and the while loop doesn't work porpertly on crontab because of this line: ping_test=ping('8.8.8.8').

I supose that the problem comes from ping3 module.

Thank you for your answer Teejay Bruno.